# Dynamic Array Output Problem

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am working on a homework assignment where I had to convert all of the static arrays in a program into dynamic arrays using pointers. I am pretty sure I am understanding the concept, I have made the changes and my program runs. The problem is with my output results. I suspect I am inputting the data incorrectly from the file I am using. Here is a pic of my issue as well as relevent code:

EDITS FROM 9/21 AFTER THIS POINT:

**Output & Data file:**
[image]

**main**

```
#include "Ch9_Ex7.h"

int main()
{
    int numCandidates;
    string *allCandidates;
    int *votes;
    int index, totalVotes;
    ifstream infile;

    allCandidates = new string[1];
    votes = new int[1];


    infile.open("./Ch9_Ex7Data.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open input file. Program terminates!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

// read number of candidates

    readVotes (infile, votes, allCandidates, numCandidates);

    //delete [] votes;
    //delete [] allCandidates;
```

**Input Function:**

```
#include "Ch9_Ex7.h"

void readVotes (ifstream & infile, int *&votes,
                string *&allCandidates, int & numCandidates)
{

//    read number of candidates
    infile >> numCandidates;
    infile.ignore();  // carriage return

    //delete [] votes;
    //delete [] allCandidates;

    allCandidates = new string[numCandidates];
    votes = new int[numCandidates];

    for (int index = 0; index < numCandidates; index++)
    {
        infile >> votes[index];
        infile.ignore();  // space
        getline(infile, allCandidates[index]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your idea is good. char* means a string not an array of strings. Keep digging, it's a nice homework.

Comment: +1 Just for knowing how to ask a question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an array of one `char` and one `int` with this code:

```
allCandidates = new char[1];
votes = new int[1];
```

I believe you meant:

```
allCandidates = new char[numCandidates];
votes = new int[numCandidates];
```

which creates dynamic arrays of size `numCandidates`.

Also, as you are inputting names of candidates you probably wanted to use `std::string` like so:

```
string *allCandidates;
allCandidates = new string[numCandidates];
```

(Thanks to Ben Voigt for pointing that out) And since you're inputting their full name you'll need to input it differently. Perhaps use `getline()`:

```
getline(cin, allCandidates[i]);
```

In response to your edit:

You will have to pass your pointers as references like so:

```
void readVotes (ifstream & infile, int *&votes, string *&allCandidates, int & numCandidates)
```

and free them in `main()`

```
delete[] votes;
delete[] allCandidates;
```

Comment: `new string[numCandidates]`, more likely.

Comment: I declare those statements before numCandidates is input from the text file. numCandidates is input in a function that both array pointers are past to so using [1] is just temporary until they get to that input function.

Comment: @mwmnj You'll have to move the `new` statement till after you get the input then. Either that or you have to deallocate it and reallocate it when you get the input but that would be kind of pointless.

Comment: create your arrays after you get the numcandidates in readVotes function
`infile >> numCandidates;
string *allCandidates;
allCandidates = new std::string[numCandidates];`

Comment: The reason I can't do that is because the arrays are passed to this input function: "readVotes (infile, votes, allCandidates, numCandidates);" If I dont allocate before calling the function I get an error. I am working on deallocating and reallocating inside the input function now to see if that will work

Comment: I am getting the error "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'allCandidates' is being used without being initialized."

Comment: ^ when I remove the "new" statements and put them inside of the input function

Comment: @mwmnj Well I can't figure out what's wrong. Perhaps you could edit your question with some code?

Comment: @quasiverse, Sure, I added more to the first snippet of main for a little more context, and added the new statements in the input function. Can you see a bit more what I am talking about? (Still working on fixing the string issue)

Comment: @quasiverse, Seems I got the code to work after passing the pointers by reference and changing the one pointer to string like you suggested. The odd thing though is it only works with my ghettot fab new statements. The program wont run correctly if I use the new statements in the input function and the delete statements in main. If you look at the newly edited code you'll see I have kept your suggested method in as comments.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is absolutely terrible design, so please don't do this outside the scope of this exercise.

Now, on to the question. If you want to create a dynamic object (or array) somewhere and pass the pointer to it back, you should take the pointer by reference. You also have to read the names into a string, not into a single character.

```
void readVotes (std::ifstream & infile, int * & votes, std::string * & allCandidates, int & numCandidates)
{
  // read numCandidates

  votes = new int[numCandidates];
  allCandidates = new std::string[numCandidates];

  // populate
}
```

The caller has to remember to clean up:

```
int main()
{
  int n;
  int * votes;
  std::string * names;

  readVotes(std::cin, votes, names, n);

  // ...

  delete[] votes;
  delete[] names;
}
```

(In a real-world situation, I would have the function return a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>`.)